# Comma in "Tomorrow, I will go to the store"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I seem to remember being taught to use a comma after introductory phrases, such as in `Tomorrow, I will go to the store.` However, a friend of mine says a comma is not needed here. Is the comma correct, incorrect, or optional? 
Would it make a difference if the introductory phrase were longer? `After breakfast tomorrow, I will go to the store.` 
Thanks!

Comment: I think the comma in the shorter example is optional (either way is fine) but the longer example needs the comma.

Comment: More like a probable duplicate...:-)

Comment: The candidate duplicate mentioned above actually addresses the situation where there is a second, parenthetical, introductory element.